# Validation with specfic input types generated from an XML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the midst of trying to come up with the best way for some validation within a generic MVC based XML which outputs the following.

```
<input name="xxxx" value="xxxx" ValidationType="Email" IsRequired="True" />
```

Basically if things contain certain elements, we validate it, if it's required than we do, if not, we don't etc etc. I tried some things but it seems the best way to do this would be a the JQuery "contains" method. I also know that that "ValidationType" is not really a valid attribute of input, but the XML outputs it this way. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks. I'm trying to do this as non complicated as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jquery [validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). You can validated elements with class-based attributes and add custom validation if need be. for example, should you need an input required. The output would look like this.

```
<input name="xxxx" value="xxxx" class="required" />
```

for email validation you can use

```
<input name="xxxx" value="xxxx" class="required email" />
```

Then execute the .valid() function to validated

Comment: cool! thanks for your answer. I've used validate before and it's pretty slick.